# Siebel Open UI Resizing Image Applet

Tags: sapui5, siebel

The new Siebel Open UI, has improve visualization. I have taken a cue from the Card Applet to meet a requirement of an image applet.
I have a created a simple applet with just one field which is the           image source path from the contact BC , the html type for the field is an image control and the field retrieval type is Field Data, everything works fine except that I cant resize the image to a fixed size like the card applet for example i want the image to be resized to 200px by 200px.
See Image attached within.
have tried looking for the css attribute for the image control but I could not find it, will appreciate suggestion on this solution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Alexander has given the perfect clue , find the css properties and edit it in this case use

```
.mceGridField.siebui-value.mceField > span > a > img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a similar requirement. I used custom css in the Siebel theme, something like this:

```
.siebui-icon-contactfilename>img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}
```

Doing this I could resize the image to 90x90 px:

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have tried this.You can set height/width css atribute to resize image,

You can directly set this in html attribute of control in applet. For example,

http://www.askmesiebel.com/2014/02/siebel-fields-validation-through-html-attributes/

If this is not your answer, please explain your question.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dave, this is the first reply am getting and it is very logical thou I will have to go to the client site to implement this, so with Open UI card applet, there are css properties such as                           .siebui-tile-container                                                                              .siebui-tile .siebui-tile-image                                                                   .siebui-form-data img

Comment: Thanks so much @Dave, this is the first reply am getting and it is very logical thou I will have to go to the client site to implement this, 
so with Open UI card applet, there are css properties such as 
.siebui-tile-container 
.siebui-tile .siebui-tile-image 
.siebui-form-data img 

But with my own applet there is no standard css that controls a field image size , so u suggesting in the html attribute 

for the applet control I shud add a code ? or a css style ?
for example 

width: 118px;
height: 118px

Comment: Yes, add height/width in control only (Here I am refering to Siebel tools). Else add custom class to your image and tag css with it. (Client side solution). Then add this css in theme-base.css file or in a new css file and register new css file in theme js file.

For ex.
HTML:

<div class="container">
<img src="something.png" />
</div>


CSS:

.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
}

/* resize images */
.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Comment: Thanks Dave , but the first option did not work , can u suggest the exact code I put in the HTML Attribute for the control applet I added width: 118px; height: 118px and that did not work , for the second part am a bit lost , I have the basic knowledge of open ui , such as Presentation Model and Physical Render, so how how to I add a class to my Image, I just want to be clear is a BC field and a control on the applet which is based on the Image Source Field,

Comment: I have tried the following on html attribute style="height:152px; width:152px;"

{ width: 200px; height: 120px; }


{ style="height:152px; width:152px;" };   But they didnt work, any suggestions?